# Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 - Invalid Handle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

All,

We have a problem in one of the applications whereby the application writes a log as below

```
DBError exception occurred in ORA9IConnection::determineAudSid(StmtFree)
   Invalid Handle
```

The Oracle version is Oracle 10.2.0.1.0

This error happens in a random manner.

I could not find any mention of this error on Google. There is no information in DB Alert file as well and nothing generated in .trc files in Oracle dump directory.

We have checked the table spaces and file systems and everything seems to be alright. There is no shortage of space and nothing that indicates that the file system might be corrupt.

What could be the issue? What could I do to analyze this error in detail and resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what language and/or API your application is coded in.

As there is not an ORA-xxxxx error message, this is (apparently?) not an Oracle Database error.

Just from reading the error message:

```
DBError exception occurred in ORA9IConnection::determineAudSid(StmtFree)
   Invalid Handle
```

And knowing a bit about how coding for a database works, it seems like you're trying to free a statement (StmtFree), but passing a statement handle that isn't valid (Invalid Handle).

This could happen if the statement handle is lost, corrupted, or possibly already freed.

For a better answer, you'll need to ask a better question.

What language/API are you using?  Can you show us the code?

Comment: Thanks Mark. The app is in Java. Unfortunately we don't have the code but what you suggest in your answers seems to be valid in this scneario. The statement handle is lost and I attribute it to a network latency issue. I generated some AWRs and we see 81% wait in "SQL*Net more data from client" network class event. We are checking with the datacentre folks if they did some change in the network setting. I will post the developments shortly.